# Android Kotlin: Serialize string to json string with Gson

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, gson

Giving a string, I'd like to format it as json string with Gson.

What I expect is from "email" to get "{"email" : "$email"}"

I can obviously do

```
fun serializeUserEmail(email: String): String {
    return "{\"email\" : \"$email\"}"
}
```

and this is what I'm currently doing, and of course I could also create an "Email" class with just one property and use

```
Gson().toJson(Email())
```

but none of them are among my expectations. I'd like to do it with just Gson, but not sure it is really possible.

I tried just

```
Gson().toJson(strEmail)
```

to no avail. It just returns the same input string, but with double quotes inside, like ""email"".

There is no problem at all with the above function (the one I'm currently using), it's just that I'm trying to replace everything related to json serialization with Gson.

Comment: If your project is pure kotlin I recommend kotlinx.serialization ([link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#json-element-builders)). With it you can `buildJsonObject { put("email", email) }` to get a json object that when `.toString()`-ed is represented by your desired JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I expect is from "email" to get "{"email" : "$email"}"

That is not a JSON string. That is a JSON object. See [the JSON documentation](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types), or any number of other resources on the JSON data format.

> It just returns the same input string, but with double quotes inside, like ""email"".

If `strEmail` is `"email"`, then that is the correct output. `""email""` is a JSON string representation of `"email"`.

> it's just that I'm trying to replace everything related to json serialization with Gson

Then you already have your solution:

> I could also create an "Email" class with just one property and use `Gson().toJson(Email())`

Note that Gson is no longer being actively maintained outside of bug fixes. Most of the original Gson developers are now contributing to [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi), as I understand it.